# How can I trigger CSS layout recalculation after Javascript DOM updates?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I often find that if I create or reparent DOM nodes in javascript, the CSS engine doesn't recalculate the sizes of the parent containers. This happens in Firefox and Chrome.

For example, the `body` might stay the same size while new content overflows the bottom. If I resize the window the body grows, but it doesn't "lock in" to its correct size until the window is sized to be *at least* as big as the `body` should be.

Is there a way to trigger a full layout recomputation in Javascript?

Comment: Sounds like you're doing something wrong in your styling, as this shouldn't really be an issue ?

Comment: Do you have these set? `html { height: 100%; }
body { min-height: 100%; }`

Comment: I'm using [this](http://peterned.home.xs4all.nl/examples/csslayout1.html) method.

Comment: Can you give us a simple HTML example?

Answer (score 1):

I can able to trigger CSS Engine via:

```
document.body.style.zoom = 1.0000001;
setTimeout(function(){document.body.style.zoom = 1;},50); //allow some time to flush the css buffer.
```

For every time after resizing the window use the following:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if(this.resizeTO) clearTimeout(this.resizeTO);
    this.resizeTO = setTimeout(function() {
        $(this).trigger('resizeEnd');
    }, 500);
});
$(window).bind('resizeEnd', function() {
    document.body.style.zoom = 1.0000001;
    setTimeout(function(){document.body.style.zoom = 1;},50);
});
```

Comment: Zoom changes may trigger a redraw, but not a box recomputing. Seems at least firefox' current parsing engine will only recompute a layout component if there's an actual size change on that specific element...

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger a repaint from JavaScript by setting a CSS style to an innocuous value, e.g.

```
document.body.style.zIndex = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I tend to put a random `className` on the `<html>` element, using:

```
document.documentElement.className = 'reflow_' + (new Date()).getTime();
```

which creates:

```
<html class="reflow_1483757400611">
```

Tried and tested on everything from Android Browser 4 to Smart TV's via [camposat.tv](http://www.camposat.tv)

Answer (score 0):

The browser does recompute the geometry of all elements after DOM manipulation. One likely reason you might see an element "stuck" at a certain height even after its content has changed is this CSS rule:

```
body { height: 100% };
```

It tells the browser, make the `body` element as large in height as the viewport regardless of its content.

Try changing it to:

```
body { min-height: 100% };
```

This will tell the browser to make `body` at least as large in height as the viewport or larger if there is more content.